# Duplicate hourly met data into multiple rows in R, without loops

Tags: r

I have what is a simple problem but cannot figure it out. I am work in R. I have two dataframes as shown below. The first is instrument data collected every 15 mins. The second is hourly met data.

```
Instrument Data
date        time    level
11/12/2019  11.00   3
11/12/2019  11.15   4
11/12/2019  11.30   5
11/12/2019  11.45   6
11/12/2019  12.00   3
11/12/2019  12.15   3
11/12/2019  12.30   3
11/12/2019  12.45   7
12/12/2019  11.00   6
12/12/2019  11.15   5
12/12/2019  11.30   8
12/12/2019  11.45   4
12/12/2019  12.00   2
12/12/2019  12.15   4
12/12/2019  12.30   6
12/12/2019  12.45   2
12/12/2019  13.00   3
```

and

```
Met data
    date        time    temp
    11/12/2019  11.00   12.3
    11/12/2019  12.00   12.0
    12/12/2019  11.00   22.2
    12/12/2019  12.00   22.6
```

What I try to do is copy the temperature information into the instrument data from the Met data dataframe for each hour and duplicate it for the times I do not have. So it should look something like this

```
date        time    level   temp
11/12/2019  11.00   3       12.3
11/12/2019  11.15   4       12.3
11/12/2019  11.30   5       12.3
11/12/2019  11.45   6       12.3
11/12/2019  12.00   3       12.0
11/12/2019  12.15   3       12.0
11/12/2019  12.30   3       12.0
11/12/2019  12.45   7       12.0
12/12/2019  11.00   6       22.2
12/12/2019  11.15   5       22.2
12/12/2019  11.30   8       22.2
12/12/2019  11.45   4       22.2
12/12/2019  12.00   2       22.6
12/12/2019  12.15   4       22.6
12/12/2019  12.30   6       22.6
12/12/2019  12.45   2       22.6
12/12/2019  13.00   3       NA
```

If I am working in Python then I can do this with a simple loop, extract each date in turn, compare the hours and then duplicate the data. I know R loops usually replaced with apply or variants but I cannot see how to use these to do what I need. Can anyone help? It has to be in R to fit in with the rest of my code.

Comment: please always share your data as code, not as formated tables, so we can reproduce it.

You can paste the output of `dput(dataframe_name)` into the question, for every data.frame

Comment: I was not familiar with dput. Thank you. I shall do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clean `join` operation.
We can `left_join` the tables, then `fill` the resulting missing values in the `temp` variable.

**Answer**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(Instrument_Data, Met_Data) |> 
    fill(temp, .direction = 'down')

         date  time level temp
1  11/12/2019 11.00     3 12.3
2  11/12/2019 11.15     4 12.3
3  11/12/2019 11.30     5 12.3
4  11/12/2019 11.45     6 12.3
5  11/12/2019 12.00     3 12.0
6  11/12/2019 12.15     3 12.0
7  11/12/2019 12.30     3 12.0
8  11/12/2019 12.45     7 12.0
9  12/12/2019 11.00     6 22.2
10 12/12/2019 11.15     5 22.2
11 12/12/2019 11.30     8 22.2
12 12/12/2019 11.45     4 22.2
13 12/12/2019 12.00     2 22.6
14 12/12/2019 12.15     4 22.6
15 12/12/2019 12.30     6 22.6
16 12/12/2019 12.45     2 22.6
17 12/12/2019 13.00     3 22.6
```

**data**

```
Instrument_Data <- data.frame(
    date = c("11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019"),
    time = c(11.00, 11.15, 11.30, 11.45, 12.00, 12.15, 12.30, 12.45, 11.00, 11.15, 11.30, 11.45, 12.00, 12.15, 12.30, 12.45, 13.00),
    level = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 7, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3)
)

Met_Data <- data.frame(
    date = c("11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019"),
    time = c(11.00, 12.00, 11.00, 12.00),
    temp = c(12.3, 12.0, 22.2, 22.6)
)
```

**minor issue**

This solution may not work properly if the temp variable is missing for some hours.
As we can see, the output from the answer above is slightly off, with the last value filled the wrong way.
To minimize potential issues, we can create an intermediary `hour` column, and `fill` grouped by hour:

```
left_join(Instrument_Data, Met_Data) |> 
    mutate(hour = str_extract(time, '\\d+')) |> 
    group_by(hour) |> 
    fill(temp, .direction = 'down') |> 
    select(-hour) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 17 × 5
   hour  date        time level  temp
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 11    11/12/2019  11       3  12.3
 2 11    11/12/2019  11.2     4  12.3
 3 11    11/12/2019  11.3     5  12.3
 4 11    11/12/2019  11.4     6  12.3
 5 12    11/12/2019  12       3  12  
 6 12    11/12/2019  12.2     3  12  
 7 12    11/12/2019  12.3     3  12  
 8 12    11/12/2019  12.4     7  12  
 9 11    12/12/2019  11       6  22.2
10 11    12/12/2019  11.2     5  22.2
11 11    12/12/2019  11.3     8  22.2
12 11    12/12/2019  11.4     4  22.2
13 12    12/12/2019  12       2  22.6
14 12    12/12/2019  12.2     4  22.6
15 12    12/12/2019  12.3     6  22.6
16 12    12/12/2019  12.4     2  22.6
17 13    12/12/2019  13       3  NA
```

Comment: Your longer answer is what I was about to give also. But I was going to also include the date, only to cover any other issues.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the wrong solution (apply) when something different (fill) was needed. I did not know R fill function. I will try that.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, you are right. It is probably safer to group_by hour AND date

Answer (score 2):

Now that dplyr has non-equi joins you can do this all in the join step

```r
library(dplyr)

Instrument_Data %>%
  left_join(Met_Data, join_by(date, time >= time),
    multiple = "last",
    suffix = c("_instrument", "_met")
  )
#>          date time_instrument level time_met temp
#> 1  11/12/2019           11.00     3       11 12.3
#> 2  11/12/2019           11.15     4       11 12.3
#> 3  11/12/2019           11.30     5       11 12.3
#> 4  11/12/2019           11.45     6       11 12.3
#> 5  11/12/2019           12.00     3       12 12.0
#> 6  11/12/2019           12.15     3       12 12.0
#> 7  11/12/2019           12.30     3       12 12.0
#> 8  11/12/2019           12.45     7       12 12.0
#> 9  12/12/2019           11.00     6       11 22.2
#> 10 12/12/2019           11.15     5       11 22.2
#> 11 12/12/2019           11.30     8       11 22.2
#> 12 12/12/2019           11.45     4       11 22.2
#> 13 12/12/2019           12.00     2       12 22.6
#> 14 12/12/2019           12.15     4       12 22.6
#> 15 12/12/2019           12.30     6       12 22.6
#> 16 12/12/2019           12.45     2       12 22.6
#> 17 12/12/2019           13.00     3       12 22.6
```

Data taken from @GuedesBF's answer

```r
Instrument_Data <- data.frame(
    date = c("11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019"),
    time = c(11.00, 11.15, 11.30, 11.45, 12.00, 12.15, 12.30, 12.45, 11.00, 11.15, 11.30, 11.45, 12.00, 12.15, 12.30, 12.45, 13.00),
    level = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 7, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3)
)

Met_Data <- data.frame(
    date = c("11/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "12/12/2019"),
    time = c(11.00, 12.00, 11.00, 12.00),
    temp = c(12.3, 12.0, 22.2, 22.6)
)
```

Edit: As Friede notes in the comments, this is not quite right when your `Met_Data` doesn't contain temperatures for all the integer times in the `Instrument_Data`. In that case you would need something else in addition to the join. e.g., add the following

```r
  mutate(temp = replace(temp, floor(time_instrument) > time_met, NA_real_))
```

Comment: `#> 17 12/12/2019           13.00     3       12 22.6` does not look good in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found a more concise base R approach yet.
Given the kind [data provision by @GuedesBF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128651/20002111), we might try

```r
x = merge(Instrument_Data, Met_Data, all.x = TRUE) 
x$tt = floor(x$time)
x["temp"] = x[(i = !duplicated(x[c("date", "tt")])), "temp"][cumsum(i)]
x$tt = NULL
x
         date  time level temp
1  11/12/2019 11.00     3 12.3
2  11/12/2019 11.15     4 12.3
3  11/12/2019 11.30     5 12.3
4  11/12/2019 11.45     6 12.3
5  11/12/2019 12.00     3 12.0
6  11/12/2019 12.15     3 12.0
7  11/12/2019 12.30     3 12.0
8  11/12/2019 12.45     7 12.0
9  12/12/2019 11.00     6 22.2
10 12/12/2019 11.15     5 22.2
11 12/12/2019 11.30     8 22.2
12 12/12/2019 11.45     4 22.2
13 12/12/2019 12.00     2 22.6
14 12/12/2019 12.15     4 22.6
15 12/12/2019 12.30     6 22.6
16 12/12/2019 12.45     2 22.6
17 12/12/2019 13.00     3   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use an *hour* column.

```
> merge(
+   transform(Instrument_Data, hour=substr(time, 1, 2)), 
+   transform(Met_Data, hour=time, time=NULL), 
+   all=TRUE
+ )
         date hour  time level temp
1  11/12/2019   11 11.15     4 12.3
2  11/12/2019   11 11.30     5 12.3
3  11/12/2019   11 11.45     6 12.3
4  11/12/2019   11 11.00     3 12.3
5  11/12/2019   12 12.15     3 12.0
6  11/12/2019   12 12.30     3 12.0
7  11/12/2019   12 12.45     7 12.0
8  11/12/2019   12 12.00     3 12.0
9  12/12/2019   11 11.15     5 22.2
10 12/12/2019   11 11.30     8 22.2
11 12/12/2019   11 11.45     4 22.2
12 12/12/2019   11 11.00     6 22.2
13 12/12/2019   12 12.15     4 22.6
14 12/12/2019   12 12.30     6 22.6
15 12/12/2019   12 12.45     2 22.6
16 12/12/2019   12 12.00     2 22.6
17 12/12/2019   13 13.00     3   NA
```

THX *@GuedesBF* for data.

Comment: Great answers everybody. Thank you. I have learned much about R language now. I implemented the last one. So very simple.